# Video streaming from Android camera to Wowza server. (RTMP)

Tags: android, rtmp, http-live-streaming

I am trying to stream video from Android to Wowza server, using RTMP. 
Android doesn't support RTMP, but i found this [Aftek library](http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-RTMP-library.shtml).

My question 1: Anyone has any experience of using this library for stream from Android to Wowza?

My question 2: Are there another solutions to use RTMP on Android for streaming video(H.264) + audio (AAC)?

My question 3 (optional): It is possible to stream LIVE video from android camera using HTTP Live?

For all questions examples will be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

http://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/

I have used this in the past, and it is open source. It may work well for you.

Comment: Yes, I saw it (no documentation, Chinese language, poor example, not support h.264), but creating red5 server on the android phone - not the way I want to go. And tell me please, how you use it (for what purpose)?

Comment: Just download the rtmp_client_src.zip. It runs from scratch. You do not need red5 server on the phone. The code just user some server libraries, it does not instantiate the server on the device. I used this to create at rtmp client and publish video to a wowza server. It works fine.

Comment: okay, but I need to decode to h.264 (nothing else). Рow to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg library and RTSP protocol. I can't provide an example but this the way.

Comment: You don't understand my question. I know what I can use RTSP (it's very simple), but I NEED to use RTMP. You have any information about this?

Comment: Non, sorry. Just found this https://github.com/mogo29/Android-RTMP

Comment: I found this http://www.smaxe.com/juvclient.jsf. It says that Java5 or later compatible (Android compatible)

Comment: Yes, I also found it, but it's not free (Note that an evaluation license is issued only once per person and will terminate in 30 days from the date of issuance.), but thank you for help.